# Mouse activity slowing down WPF graphics demo

Tags: c#, wpf

Below is a small graphics demo in WPF. It looks something like this:

[image]

When it's running, if I move the mouse around the main area of the window, the animation slows down (at least on my system). If I move the mouse pointer out of the window entirely, the animation come back up to speed.

Any suggestions for how to prevent the mouse movement interfering with the animation speed?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WPF_Golden_Section
{
    class DrawingVisualElement : FrameworkElement
    {
        public DrawingVisual visual;

        public DrawingVisualElement() { visual = new DrawingVisual(); }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return 1; } }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) { return visual; }
    }

    public static class CanvasUtils
    {
        public static Canvas SetCoordinateSystem(this Canvas canvas, Double xMin, Double xMax, Double yMin, Double yMax)
        {
            var width = xMax - xMin;
            var height = yMax - yMin;

            var translateX = -xMin;
            var translateY = height + yMin;

            var group = new TransformGroup();

            group.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(translateX, -translateY));
            group.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(canvas.ActualWidth / width, canvas.ActualHeight / -height));

            canvas.RenderTransform = group;

            return canvas;
        }
    }

    public static class ColorUtils
    {
        public static Color Write(this Color color)
        {
            Console.Write("Color[{0} {1} {2} {3}]", color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);

            return color;
        }

        static byte ColorComponentToByte(double n)
        {
            return 
                (byte)
                    Math.Round(Math.Min(Math.Max(n, 0), 1) * 255);
        }

        public static Color Rgb(double r, double g, double b)
        {
            return
                Color.FromRgb(
                    ColorComponentToByte(r),
                    ColorComponentToByte(g),
                    ColorComponentToByte(b));
        }

        public static Color SetArgb(this Color color, double a, double r, double g, double b)
        {
            color.A = ColorComponentToByte(a);
            color.R = ColorComponentToByte(r);
            color.G = ColorComponentToByte(g);
            color.B = ColorComponentToByte(b);

            return color;
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Width = 600;
            Height = 600;

            var dockPanel = new DockPanel();

            Content = dockPanel;

            var slider =
                new Slider()
                {
                    Minimum = 0.1,
                    Maximum = 10,
                    LargeChange = 0.001,
                    Value = 1
                };

            dockPanel.Children.Add(slider);

            DockPanel.SetDock(slider, Dock.Top);

            var incrementSlider =
                new Slider()
                {
                    Maximum = 0.001,
                    Minimum = 0.00001,
                    Value = 0.0001
                };

            dockPanel.Children.Add(incrementSlider);


            DockPanel.SetDock(incrementSlider, Dock.Top);

            var pauseButton = new Button() { Content = "Pause" };

            dockPanel.Children.Add(pauseButton);

            DockPanel.SetDock(pauseButton, Dock.Top);

            var canvas = new Canvas();

            dockPanel.Children.Add(canvas);

            DockPanel.SetDock(canvas, Dock.Top);

            SizeChanged += (s, e) => canvas.SetCoordinateSystem(-400, 400, -400, 400);

            var element = new DrawingVisualElement();

            Action draw = () =>
                {
                    canvas.Children.Clear();

                    // var element = new DrawingVisualElement();

                    using (var dc = element.visual.RenderOpen())
                    {
                        for (var i = 0.0; i < 720.0; i += slider.Value)
                        {
                            var radius = Math.Sin(i / 720.0 * Math.PI) * 30;

                            var phi = (1 + Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2;

                            var omega = 2 * Math.PI * (phi - 1) * i;

                            var x = Math.Cos(omega) * 0.5 * i;
                            var y = Math.Sin(omega) * 0.5 * i;

                            dc.DrawEllipse(
                                new SolidColorBrush(ColorUtils.Rgb(i / 360.0, i / 360.0, 0.25)),
                                new Pen(Brushes.Black, Math.Max(radius / 6, 1)),
                                new Point(x, y),
                                radius / 2,
                                radius / 2);
                        }
                    }

                    canvas.Children.Add(element);
                };

            slider.ValueChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                Title = slider.Value.ToString() + "     " + incrementSlider.Value;
                draw();
            };

            var timer = new DispatcherTimer();

            timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (slider.Value < 10.0)
                        slider.Value += incrementSlider.Value;
                };

            timer.Start();

            pauseButton.Click += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (timer.IsEnabled)
                        timer.Stop();
                    else
                        timer.Start();
                };

            slider.Value = 3.5;
            incrementSlider.Value = 0.00001;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the third Animation option in WPF, CompositionTarget.Rendering event, then I found no slowdown. I have adjusted the code in your sample from the line with slider.ValueChanged:

```
        slider.Value = 3.5;
        incrementSlider.Value = 0.00001;

        EventHandler renderer = (s, e) =>
        {
            if (slider.Value < 10.0)
                slider.Value += incrementSlider.Value;

            //Title = slider.Value.ToString() + "     " + incrementSlider.Value;
            draw();
            _frameCounter++;
        };

        CompositionTarget.Rendering += renderer;
        pauseButton.Click += (sender, args) => CompositionTarget.Rendering -= renderer;

        var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
                          {
                              Title = string.Format("fps: {0}", _frameCounter);
                              _frameCounter = 0;
                          };

        timer.Start();
```

CompositionTarget.Rendering fires at a fixed 60 fps rate unless heavy machine load. You can find code on the internet to adjust for framedrops and avoid visible slow downs.

I have no good explanation for the slow down due to the mouse activity in your example. My first thought would be that it is a bottleneck in the routed event infra, but adjusting the timer interval or refactoring by extracting the draw method from the ValueChanged event did not seem to solve the problem.

BTW I liked your sample.

Comment: Hi Grafix. Thanks for the suggestion. If you max out the second slider in your version and in mine, you'll notice that it runs much slower in the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` version. So I think it's running smoothly simply because it's iterating at a much slower rate. My original version runs fast, but there should be some way to prevent the mouse from interfering.

Comment: I have to see monday what you mean, the code is on machine at work. But isn't it 'slower' because the event is fixed at max of 60fps? Your code tries to update as much as possible so it will update those slider values faster. But then again I should check to see myself.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the hit testing. You could try setting the [IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) to false on the Canvas.

Comment: I gave that a shot but it didn't seem to help. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: I ran your project and if you look at the CPU usage you'll see it's maxed out while your app is running. I think you should look at setting a reasonable Interval on the timer and adjusting your calculations.